# AWS ECS Fargate request not reaching task container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

So I setup a aws ecs cluster to run a docker image of [Valhalla](https://hub.docker.com/r/gisops/valhalla) service almost as-is.

Issue : target group seems to be not able to check for cluster health, like if the health request was reaching the cluster, but container is not "forwarding" the request to Valhalla.

Description :

1. I created a repository on AWS ECR, and pushed a docker image of `gisops/valhalla` with only the `valhalla.json` file changed.
   Here is the valhalla [configuration](https://gist.github.com/nicolasUpway/edc3eb5bbc0e45986c550c75255ede3a) I used.
   Note that I changed the default listening port from 8002 to 80.
2. I created a ECS Fargate cluster, and a service that uses this [task definition](https://gist.github.com/nicolasUpway/2ba952f8cf4545c129ef72102aa40f7d) to launch a container that runs Valhalla.
3. The service receives traffic from an application load balancer via port 80.
   The target group is checking `/status` path on port 80.
4. All set, the task is then creating, and task logs shows that Valhalla is initializing perfectly and running.
5. However the target group is not able to check for health status : the request seems to timeout.
   If the request was reaching valhalla, the task logs would have at least show it (because valhalla logs every incoming request by default), but it doesn't.
6. Therefore fargate kills the task (`Task failed ELB health checks in (target-group {my-target-group-uri})`) (showing that the health request was reaching the cluster service indeed)

I don't think the issue is with the valhalla configuration, because I can run the same docker image locally, and it works perfectly, using :

```
docker run -dt -p 3000:80 -v /local/path/to/valhalla-files:/custom_files/ --name valhalla gisops/valhalla:latest
```

And then checking localhost:3000/status

Anyone has an idea of what could be the issue ?

Already spent a lot of time on this, and I'm out of ideas. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you have some sort of Cloudformation/Terraform template? Otherwise it will be difficult to analyse.

Comment: Also, are you sure the container is coming up at all? Sometimes this effect occurs when the service can’t launch in the first place. Check the task status in the service view of the cluster. For example, it might be that ECS can’t access the container registry to fetch the image.

Comment: hi @lxg, thanks for your feedback. No template used, sorry. The task is launching and running (cf point 4. above). It's marked as "RUNNING" by Fargate, but since the target group can't check health status, the task is tagged as unhealthy and stopped by Fargate (about 5min after its creation)

Comment: Can you launch it with a public IP and see if you can access it directly? Also, are you sure that your ALB can reach the containers through your VPC? (Subnets, SGs, NACLs etc.)

Comment: Sounds like it may be a security group issue. Please edit your question to show the security group settings for your Fargate task.

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with security group indeed. Thank you @MarkB & lxg ! I used an existing security group instead of creating a new one, and the old security group did not have the right inbound rule. Now everything is working :)